# Deleting every other node of a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I searched previous asked questions but could not find exactly what I was looking for. I was curious if anyone had any idea on how to delete every other node of a linked list. I have a function called duplicate which take `1 2 3` and turns it into `1 1 2 2 3 3`. Deleting every other node would work just fine, no need to compare them or anything. If anyone has any insights. Please don't just post source code.

Heres what I was trying to do but wasn't working.

```
Node *current;
Node *undo;
for (current = front, undo = current->next->next; 
undo != NULL; current = current->next, undo = current->next->next){
    current->next = undo;
}
```

This will output `1 1 2 2 3 3 3`

Thank you for any help. I can comment back later to clarify any misconceptions.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. If you want to duplicate elements, then why are you saying that you are 'deleting' nodes?

Comment: Sorry essentially I meant, deleting every other node.

Comment: You are not deleting nodes instead of that you are just changing the links...if you want I can add the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original code:

```
for (current = front, undo = current->next->next; 
   undo != NULL; 
   current = current->next, // this moves current on before you use it's next pointer
   undo = current->next->next){
     current->next = undo;
}
```

To fix, without deallocating the unwanted nodes (assumes an even number of nodes):

```
for (current = front;  current != NULL; current = current->next){
      current->next = current->next->next
}
```

To handle odd length lists, and delete memory of removed nodes:

```
for (current = front;  current && current->next ; current = current->next){
      undo = current->next;
      current->next = current->next->next
      delete undo;
}
```

Comment: What would you recommend to fix that?

Comment: _undo = current->next->next_  what if current->next is null? will it not create seg fault?

Comment: Thanks man. That pretty much did it. Make perfect sense I really over complicated it. Now you mentioned with out deallocating. So how would I deallocate the nodes?

Answer (score 0):

I would use [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) (or perhaps [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) if so needed) and [std::copy_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [std::remove_if](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) in C++11.

Otherwise, remember the address of the pointer to be modified, something like:

```
Node**undoad = &front;
int cnt=0;
for (current=front; current != NULL; current=current->next) {
  if (cnt%2 == 1) {
    Node*undo = *undoad;
    undoad = &current->next; 
    if (undo) undo->next = current->next;
  }
  cnt++;
}
```

However, the above probably is a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak): you may need to use `delete` somewhere.

Comment: I cannot sadly :(

I have to use singly linked list.